# The size of tensor a (20) must match the size of tensor b (25) at non-singleton dimension 1 for pad_sequence() in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

My Code :

```
  import torch.nn.utils.rnn as r

  a = torch.ones([1, 20])
  b = torch.ones([1, 25])

  c = r.pad_sequence([a, b], batch_first=True, padding_value=0)
```

The Traceback of this code is :

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (20) must match the size of tensor b (23) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

can anybody explain to me what is this error and how to solve this?

All I wanted is to pad zeros to tensor a to make it's shape equal to b.

Comment: How would you interpret the error message?

Comment: Are you sure about   a = torch.ones([1, 20]) vs   a = torch.ones(20)

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have two sequences of length/duration of 20 and 25 samples, respectively. Both sequences have 1-dim element per time step.

PyTorch expects the element dim to be the last dim, therefore you need:

```py
c = r.pad_sequence([a.T, b.T], batch_first=True)
```

With output shape of `c` equals to `[2, 25, 1]`.